# Loop though JSON images from Tumblr API using Gatsby

Tags: json, reactjs, api, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to connect to use [Tumblr's API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) to create a image array using a Graphql request.

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import "../styles/index.scss";


const Portfolio = ( props ) => {
  const name=props.data.allTumblrPost.edges[0].node.blog_name;
  const image=props.data.allTumblrPost.edges;
  const test=props.data.allTumblrPost.edges[6].node.photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url;


    return (
        <div>
      <h1>{name}'s Portfolio</h1>

      <img src={test} />

      {image.map(({ node }, i) => {
          return (
            <div>
                <img src={node.photos} alt={`image_${node.photos}`} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Portfolio;


export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query PostQuery {
    allTumblrPost {
      edges {
        node {
          blog_name
          post_url
          photos {
            caption
            alt_sizes {
              url
            }
          }
          id
          type
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

So far, I have managed to output one single test image as shown above.
I can change the edge array value and everything works fine.
My question is how do I loop though the edge array to output all the images and pipe that data through `photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my solution to the problem below.
Turns out, the main issue I was having when querying Tumblr's API was when the post has an `iframe` or any other data that wasn't an image.

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import "../styles/index.scss"
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';


const Gallery = ( props ) => {
  const description = props.data.allTumblrPost.edges[0].node.blog.description;
  const page = props.data.allTumblrPost.edges[0].node.blog.url;
  const image = props.data.allTumblrPost.edges;


    return (
        <div class="gallery">
          <Navbar />
          <Layout>
          <Helmet><html class="gallery" lang="en" /></Helmet>
          <SEO title="Gallery" />
          <p>{description}</p>
          {image.map(({ node }) => {
              return (
                    <img src={node.photos[0].original_size.url} alt="#" />
              )
            })}
            <a href={page}>Click here for more →</a>
            </Layout>
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Gallery;


export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query PostQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
      allTumblrPost {
        edges {
          node {
            caption
            blog {
              title
              description
              url
            }
            post_url
            photos {
              original_size {
                url
              }
              alt_sizes {
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading up on [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Arguably the MDN docs aren't the most beginner-friendly, so I'll also recommend Tania Rascia's [Examples of Map, Filter and Reduce in JavaScript](https://www.taniarascia.com/real-world-examples-of-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript/).

As for your question:

```js
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import "../styles/index.scss";

const Portfolio = (props) => {
  /**
   * Note: you will probably also want to map through the different posts.
   * Optimally this should be done in the parent component, and you'll pass
   * the `post` down as a prop.
   */
  const post = props.data.allTumblrPost.edges[0]; // only handle the first post
  const { blog_name, photos } = post.node; // destructure the photos and name

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{blog_name}'s Portfolio</h1>

      {
        // this is where you map through the post's photos
        photos.map((photo, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={photo.alt_sizes[0].url} alt={photo.caption} />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query PostQuery {
    allTumblrPost {
      edges {
        node {
          blog_name
          post_url
          photos {
            caption
            alt_sizes {
              url
            }
          }
          id
          type
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: `.alt_sizes[0].url`

Comment: Thanks @Robin Métral. I am half way there but the same image seems to be repeating itself: `const image=props.data.allTumblrPost.edges;` with `{
        image.map(({node}, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url} alt={photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url} />
        ))
      }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, but `props.data.allTumblrPost.edges` is an array of posts, not images. You have two arrays that you need to map over, posts first, and then images for each post.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I understand that there are two arrays. What I'm trying to do is loop through the edges and not the photos. The `photos` and `alt_sizes` value should remain at [0] so basically the only number that needs to change is the edge value. When I tried your solution above, it was only outputting one single image because the edge value is set to 0.

Comment: Got it! Isn't my example enough to understand `map` and to adapt it to your code yourself, though? This is what StackOverflow is about :)

Comment: Thanks @Robin Métral, You're right! I will let you know when I come with a solution:)